# Restricting Access to a Google Code Repo, (for a good cause / reason)

Tags: svn

I recieved an email from someone at university / college asking me to restrict access to my google code repository. My repo contains solutions to the excersises for a course text book [The Elements of Computing Systems](http://www1.idc.ac.il/tecs/). I don't mind restricting access for this reason (plus my solutions aren't very good anyway) can anyone tell me how to do this? Or is it impossible as some googling suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Only open source projects can be hosted on google code. Making your source code unavailable would make it closed source. It's not possible to host closed source projects on google code. so it is indeed impossible.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to close a repo then? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that till today only open sources can hosted with Google. Couldn't found any way to do this.